# How to insert text inside of doughnut graph in vue chart JS 3.7.1

Tags: vue.js, charts, chart.js

[image]

Hello, I would like to ask how to create text inside of the doughnut graph in vue chartjs. I already copy paste the other questions posted here but it seems like it is not working on my side. Please help me with this

I tried to paste the below code in my data return and it is not working. Please enlighten me
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

```
import { Doughnut } from 'vue-chartjs/legacy'
import {
 Chart as ChartJS,
 Title,
 Tooltip,
 Legend,
 ArcElement,
 CategoryScale,
 Plugin
   } from 'chart.js'

ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, ArcElement, CategoryScale)

export default {
   name: 'DoughnutChart',
   components: {Doughnut},
   props: {
    chartId: {
        type: String,
        default: 'doughnut-chart'
    },
    width: {
        type: Number,
        default: 400
    },
    height: {
        type: Number,
        default: 200
    },
    cssClasses: {
        default: '',
        type: String
    },
    styles: {
        type: Object,
        default: () => {}
    },
    plugins: {
        type: Object,
        default: () => {}
    }
},
data() {
    return {
        reports: [],
        //multiselect
       chartData: {
            labels: ['VueJs', 'EmberJs', 'ReactJs', 'AngularJs'],
            datasets: [
                {
                backgroundColor: ['#41B883', '#E46651', '#00D8FF', 
      '#DD1B16'],
                data: [40, 20, 80, 10]
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [{
            id: 'text',
            beforeDraw: function(chart, a, b) {
            var width = chart.width,
                height = chart.height,
                ctx = chart.ctx;

            ctx.restore();
            var fontSize = (height / 114).toFixed(2);
            ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
            ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

            var text = "75%",
                textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) 
               / 2),
                textY = height / 2;

            ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
            ctx.save();
            }
        }],
    }
},
```

Comment: Please don't post your code as pictures as they are harder to search through and are harder to copy paste for people to help you. Instead paste the code directly in your question

Comment: Already updated the code